# How do I turn these .py files into an application that I can then embed into my website?

Tags: python, web-applications, exe, py2app

So I have found some code on Github for an Instagram bot that automatically likes and follows and it works great when I run it through terminal on my MacBook. I am using a Mac btw. I want to be able to turn the code into an application that I can put on my website.

The link for the code is here:
https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py

If there is a way to turn that into a usable application or even just an app where you can edit the example.py and press enter and it starts to run.

I have tried to use py2app but it wouldn't work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to compile into an executable file as you've seen, but currently not into a web app.

It might be possible later on with the advent of wasm, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: appreciate the response. Thanks!